# Gradual Color Change in Review Queues->Late Answers in Dark Mode incorrect

Tags: bug, design, dark-mode

I am using StackOverflow in dark mode (very nice by the way), and would like to bring to your attention that when in the "Review Queues"->"Late Answers" "Skip" is pressed, the answer box starts orange (correct), but turns gradually to white before going back to black (no pun intended).
I believe that the gradual color change does not take currently the dark mode in consideration, which causes this problem.
Would love to help if more information is necessary to reproduce or solve this issue.